# How do I create multiple two dimensional arrays in an enum?

Tags: java, enums

I am sort of new to java and I am currently attempting to make a small Naughts and Crosses program complete with "a.i.".

I decided to let the computer make it's move by comparing the current 2d char array to an enum of 2d arrays that have been set up with multiple scenarios and then to move accordingly. The only problem at the moment is that I am unsure as to how to make a 2d char array inside an enum with specific values. If anyone could specify as to how I would accomplish this that would be great, or maybe I'm going about the problem the wrong way?

Any help regarding the matter would be highly valued, thank-you.

Comment: Do you need to access the enum in multiple places? If not, create a class for this instead. I advise against putting any but the simplest state in an enum.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to "linearise" the data:

```
public enum Foo {
    BAR("1010"), LOL("0101");

    private final String data;

    private Foo(final String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public char[][] get2DArray() {
        // construct from data  
    }
}
```

With a transformation like:

```
1 0
0 1   =>  1001
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same way you would do any class. Not sure what you want exactly but here is an example.

```
enum Scenario {
    ONE(new char[] {
        { 'X', ' ', ' ' },
        { ' ', ' ', ' ' },
        { 'X', ' ', ' ' }
    }),
    TWO(new char[] {
        { ' ', ' ', ' ' },
        { ' ', 'X', 'X' },
        { ' ', ' ', ' ' }
    });

    private final char[] board;

    private Scenario(char[] board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public boolean matches(char[] gameBoard) {
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < board[i].length; k++) {
                if(board[i][k] != gameBoard[i][k])
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Enum is just a class and the constants are objects of that class. So you can make methods, constructors, etc. The syntax is just a little bit different.

Answer (score 1):

you might try something like this

```
    public enum ArrayCheck {
        Array1  (new int[][]{
        {1 , 0, 1},
        {1 , 0, 1},
        {1 , 0, 0}
    };),

        Array2(new int[][]{
        {1 , 0, 1},
        {1 , 0, 1},
        {1 , 0, 0}
    };)

        int[][] matrix;
        ArrayCheck(int[][] matrix) {
            this.matrix = matrix;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums can be thought of as classes where you have a static reference to named instances of that class.

Thinking this way leads you to the idea of declaring the static 2d array in the enum the same way you would any other static data in any class.

```
public enum MyEnum {

Type1,Type2;

private static int [][] _2dArr = new int[10][10];
static {
    _2dArr[0][0] = 1;
}
}
```